# /bin/sh source from stdin (from other program) not file

Tags: sh

Kind of a tricky one to name this...

Basically I have a program which when run prints on STDOUT a set of shell variables:

```
$ ./settings
SETTING_ONE="this is setting one"
SETTING_TWO="This is the second setting"
ANOTHER_SETTING="This is another setting".
```

I want to run this from within a shell script as if the STDOUT were being evaluated with `source`.

I'd like to do something like ...

```
source `./settings`
```

... but of course that doesn't work.

I know I could do:

```
./settings >/tmp/file
source /tmp/file
```

but I really don't want to do that.

Any clues?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
eval "$(./settings)"

eval "`./settings`"
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, it's /bin/sh not bash.  $() doesn't work.  I have updated the question.

Comment: @Matt: Well, sh is bash on most systems. Unless of course you meant recent Ubuntu versions, where it has been replaced with dash.

Comment: @Matt: In that case, backticks should work. But you should add the exact version of `sh` too - it could be a symlink to dash, ash, busybox... I have not seen a copy of "the real 'sh'" live.

Comment: @Matt: So you've got an ... interesting system there. Especially since almost all "sh" variations support `$( )` -- starting with Almquist's shell in [4.3BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&manpath=4.3BSD+NET%2F2) -- and it's POSIX too. *(Note: not arguing, just curious.)*

Comment: $() exists, it just doesn't work like that in this circumstance.  FreeBSD 8.2's /bin/sh

Comment: Well, it didn't when I tried it just now - now it does.  Strange - must be having a 'moment'...

Comment: `$( )` doesn't work in heirloom shell (which predates POSIX).

Answer (score 27):

On systems where `/dev/fd` is available, bash supports process substitution:

```
source <(./settings)
```

Here, `<( )` will expand to an automatically assigned path under `/dev/fd/...` from which the output of `./settings` can be read.

Comment: In the bash manual, this is called "process substitution".

Comment: Note for **macOS** users: the default Bash version 3 on mac is quite old which doesn't support this "process substitution".

Comment: Doesn't macOS use zsh by default anyway?

Comment: I meant the default pre-installed bash, not default shell. Some people don't use zsh by default. I just took them a note.

Answer (score 7):

```
declare `./settings`
```

Or of course...

```
export `./settings`
```

Test it of course...

```
export `echo -e "asdf=test\nqwerty=dvorak"` ; echo $asdf $qwerty
```

Handling whitespace:

```
eval export `./settings`
```

Comment: Aha, the `export` trick works!  Thanks

Comment: Now - how can I handle spaces in a value?

Comment: @Matt: I can't use backticks in comments, so please see edited answer.

Comment: @grawity: Yes you can... `a backtick --> \` <--` `and here's another one --> \` <--`

Comment: Note that is your `settings` is empty, `export` will spam the stdout with all existing exports. I did not find a flag to disable that behavior.

Answer (score 6):

`source /dev/stdin < ./settings`

I think /dev/stdin is a Linux only thing though.

Comment: that tries to source the content of settings.  Even with './settings' it fails with './settings': Ambiguous  (' = backtick)

Comment: `/dev/stdin` works on BSD and Cygwin, too.

Comment: Using `|`, however, is _not_ going to work (at least not exactly), because both sides of the pipe are separate subprocesses, so sourced commands would not affect the current shell.

Comment: edited to reflect that.

Comment: I like this `/dev/stdin` trick, but what your answer does is in fact equivalent to a plain `source ./settings` without executing it. One could use a here-document to overcome this: `source /dev/stdin <<EOF \n $(./settings) \n EOF`.

Comment: @tlwhitec, or herestring (if available): `source /dev/stdn <<<"$(./settings)"`. But process substitution (if available) is even shorter: `source <(./settings)`.

Comment: Note that `settings | source /dev/stdin` does actually work under `ksh`. `ksh(1)` says of pipelines: *Each command, except possibly the last, is run as a separate process*, which is different to `bash`. The "except possibly the last" really helps here!

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to provide another perspective here, as the other answers create files and don't directly pull from stdin.  I have some builds that need to send some prepared environment information to multiple scripts.  What I'm doing is preparing a bunch of Bash compatible variable assignments in a string:

```
Var1="Foo"
Var2="Bar"
Var3="Baz"
```

When I'm preparing to execute the script, I base64 encode the above multiline string and pipe it into my shell script:

```bsh
echo base64EncodedParameters | build.sh
```

In build.sh I read from stdin, base64 decode and eval the result.

```bsh
params=""
while read line; do params="${params}${line}"; done
eval `echo $params | base64 -D`

echo "Hello ${Var1} ${Var2}"
```